# How to manage my header files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to say that my package compiles ok. But I've seen people create a different include folder where they place their include file. I find this cleaner and a better practice in general and I want to follow it. The problem is I don't know how to do it without absolute reference. I don't want to use something like that:

```
#include "../../include/lib/foo.hpp"
```

my package name lets say it is upm.
I want something like

```
#include "upm/include/lib/foo.hpp"
```

or without upm even better.

I've tried
http://answers.ros.org/question/30425/include-directory-for-other-packages/

but with no success.
Any suggestions?
And generally how do you treat your header files? What it is considered good practice?
Sorry if it's naive and a bit general.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54941/how-to-manage-my-header-files./) by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One thing u can try is create a folder "include" in ur main package directory and then create another folder inside include folder which is named as package name and the add all ur include files in it.

To include the files u have to use <package_name/filename.h> in ur src file.

Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kabamaru](https://answers.ros.org/users/2240/kabamaru/) on 2013-02-11**:
well thanks a lot i've figure it out, after all .